# What does this line in PayPal's developer documentation mean?

Tags: paypal, country-codes

> Use the C2 country code for China worldwide for comparable uncontrolled price (CUP) method, bank card, and cross-border transactions.

Found on this page: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v1

I'm struggling to make sense of what it actually *means*!

I know what ISO codes are - what I am trying to figure out is why the 'C2' (China) code might be used for ALL bank card/cross-border/CUP transactions worldwide, regardless of the ACTUAL countries involved - or if that's not what it means at all!

Comment: Most probably [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2), two characters i.e. ISO 3166-1 alpha-2.

Comment: I know what ISO codes are - what I am trying to figure out is why the 'C2' (China) code might be used for ALL bank card/cross-border/CUP transactions worldwide, regardless of the ACTUAL countries involved - or if that's not what it means at all!